# ACV besides DCV in variable outputDC power supply

Tags: power-supply

Recently I have made a power supply which gives dc voltage between 1.2 ~ 30
But when I use my multimeter I can measure AC voltage too is that normal ?
Shouldn't it be zero ?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How much of an AC waveform do you see? What is its voltage? What is its frequency? Does it change as you draw current on the DC side?

Comment: Many (most, probably) multimeters are AC coupled on the AC ranges so they will read 0V if there is no ripple. If you connect the multimeter across a battery (on an AC range) what do you read?

Comment: @AndyHall the AC output is almost as twice as the DC and yes it changes as I change the DC voltage

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I can get 18  ACV out off a 9 v battery so is it my multimeter

Comment: can we say "get a new meter?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your multimeter reads significantly differently from non-zero with a battery input, your power supply is probably okay. That's a bit of a strange voltage reading- maybe 1/2 wave rectified with DC coupling.

You van try a capacitor in series with the input of the meter- maybe 10uF.